# Allowing EC2 instance to access bucket that has deny policy attached to it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a bucket with a deny policy attached to it, more or less like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "RestrictedAccess",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/someuser@somecompany",
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It is evident, that even if I grant IAM permissions to an IAM user/role to access the bucket, the above `Deny` will prevail.

Now, I want to create an EC2 instance that should also have access to this bucket.

What type of principal should I add here

```
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/someuser@somecompany",
                ]
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the ARN of the Role the EC2 instance is using to your Deny exception **and** add an explicit allow to the role for the S3 operations you wish to perform.

Comment: So if I want to allow everything, as is the case for the user `"arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/someuser@somecompany",`, I will just have to add below this line, the arn of the EC2 instance's role, right?

Comment: no, by adding entities to that list, they're jut not explicitly denied, they still need an explicit allow.

Comment: So I will **also** need an explicit allow to the corresponding EC2 role, right?